# Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels during distribute

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

> Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels.

I have this problem when I try to distribute app in Xcode. I am surprised because I distributed some days ago a new version of my app.

Here are screenshots of my app icon assets.

What I should do with this? I am using Xcode 13

[image]

[image]